# How to parse json string array with not knowing how many strings there are in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing

I want to parse one json than have an array with multiple strings, but i don't know how to do. I know how to parse json but in static method but i don't know if I've multiple string

My json is:

```
{
    "index": [
        {
            "numberOfString":"N"
            "string1":"myString1",
            "string2":"myString2",
            "stringN":"mystringN"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what do you want to do with that? What your ideal structure if you coded your model?

Comment: That inner structure is a dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of strings is unknown or can change you can decode this to a dictionary. The struct for this would be:

```
struct Response: Codable{
    var index: [[String:String]]
}
```

In your example the index var contains an array of `[String:String]`.

---

### Edit:

As you asked for an example:

I don´t know what you want to do with this and don´t know where this json comes from (file/dataStream) so it will be just a general example.

Let´s say you get this as `Data` then the next step would be to decode it.

```
let response = try JsonDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
```

this will lead to an object with a structure described in my initial answer. Now you can iterate over the dictionary in the `response` and map the values to an array for example. This could be used in a tableview for presenting.

```
let arr = response.index.map{ $1 }
```

Comment: Can you make a simple example for this type of json, please? Thank you

Comment: @EmanueleMele please see my updated answer. But please  be aware, that your question does not contain enough information to compile a more detailed example. If this is not what you meant, please add more information.

Comment: Yes thank you, I want to take the information inside the json and transfer there in string array

Comment: @EmanueleMele that´s exactly what the example shows. If this helped you solve your problem please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes thank you, i try in these days.